# URL rewriting problem

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In order to convert dynamic URLs on my site www.kitesmovie.co.in to static urls. Eg:  www.kitesmovie.co.in/stories.php?id=10 to www.kitesmovie.co.in/Barbara_Mori_Hrithik_Roshan_New_Movie.

I tried using rewriting rules in my htaccess files, but it did not work. Please tell me how to do this.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what  you are trying to achieve.
When you say "convert dynamic urls to static urls", do you really want to have user to type in the `...?id=10` and the file named `Barbara_Mori_Hrithik_Roshan_New_Movie` lives on your server? I think, it's the opposite way - you want to let the user type in the long & nice title and actually resolve it to `?id=10`
If this is the case, the @Mike's answer is nearly correct, you only have to swap the parts of the last line:

```
RewriteRule Barbara_Mori_Hrithik_Roshan_New_Movie stories.php?id=10 [R,L]
```

Another question - are you sure you have the .htaccess working? An easy way to check is to set the contents of .htaccess to

```
order deny, allow
deny from all
```

And see if you can still access that directory. If you can, this means the "deny from all" does not work. Then check your apache config - is .htaccess allowed in the particular virtualhost and/or directory.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of missing info there.  If you are using apache with mod_rewite installed, place this in your .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule stories.php?id=10 Barbara_Mori_Hrithik_Roshan_New_Movie [R,L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at this article:  http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Generally, you would use a RewriteRule something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^stories.php?id=10$  Barbara_Mori_Hrithik_Roshan_New_Movie [R=301,L]
```

If that's not working for you, then feel free to add more details to your question.